# How do I pull data from 1 table to populate a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables, A and B. Table A looks like this:

```
RECORD_NUMBER   INDEXNO      SUFFIX    FILENO    YEAR      INDEXTYPE
-------------   -----------  ------    ------    -------   ---------
123382          4037                   1019      2004
123383          4038                   1019      2003
124814          3586                   1019      2005 
117912          2007                   1019      2007
```

And table B looks like this:

```
RECORD_NUMBER   NOI_DATE     CALNO       CALTRACK_FILENO    FILENO    YEAR       CALTYPE
-------------   -----------  ---------   ---------------    ------    -------    ------- 
23421           2022-02-23   2022T0930   xxxxx              1019      1993       4  
24020           2022-02-23   2022T0931   xxxxx              1019      1994       4
14524           2022-02-23   2005T0631                      1019      2005       3
```

I need to generate a table C that would look like this:

```
CALNO       INDEXNO    FILENO    YEAR    CALTYPE    INDEXTYPE
---------   -------    ------    ----    -------    ---------
2022T0930              1019      1993    4
2022T0931              1019      1994    4
            4038       1019      2003
            4037       1019      2004
2005T0631   3586       1019      2005    3
            2007       1019      2007
```

No matter what I try, I get 12 records in table C. The join takes the first record of table A and matches it up with each record in table B, generating 3 records into table C. Then it takes the second record of table A and matches it with each record in table B generating 3 more records into table C.

At the end, I end up with 12 records in table C when I only want 7.

This is one of the scripts that I tried:

```
select * 
from calno b
full join indexno a on (b.FILENO = a.FILENO)
where b.FILENO = 1019
order by a.INDEXNO
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: The relationship between the tables isn't obvious (at least not to me). Sample code will help clarify, and so would an explanation of how they data is being matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select
  b.calno, a.indexno, 
  coalesce(a.fileno, b.fileno) as fileno,
  coalesce(a.year, b.year) as year,
  b.caltype, b.indextype 
from a
full join b on b.year = a.year and b.fileno = a.fileno
order by coalesce(a.fileno, b.fileno), coalesce(a.year, b.year)
```

The ordering of the rows is not clear in the question, particularly in the presence of multiple `fileno`.